# TypeScript - trouble with accessing indexes from one type in another

Tags: typescript

I have a function 'fetchData' that takes a key value object where the key represents a function name and the value is the parameter to pass into that function. The 'fetchData' function returns an object with the returned value from each of those specified functions.

The 'fetchData' function is working well, I'm just struggling with the types within it. I'm trying to make it so that any number of keys can be passed in, but they're all essentially optional, and in doing so the types returned should only be provided for those keys. I'm also trying to provide type safety on the function parameters, to ensure that the types match the requirements of each specified function.

The TypeScript is actually working in that all the validation is applied etc, but there's a few problems with type indexes within the function, so I'm looking for a bit of help on how to deal with those. I hope everything makes sense, I've tried to comment and simplify it as much as possible. Can explain more if it helps..

```js
const getA = async (query: { foop: string }) => ({
    shapeOfA: query
});
const getB = async (query: { barp: string }) => ("returnB");
const getC = async (query: { boop: string }) => ("returnC");

const modelFunctions = {
  getA,
  getB,
  getC
};

// the keys for all of our model functions, i.e. "getA", "getB", etc (strings)
type ModelFunctionKeys = keyof typeof modelFunctions;

// type of query props coming into function (e.g. { foop: "hello", ... } on getA)
type Queries = {
  [modelFunctionKey in ModelFunctionKeys]?: Parameters<
    typeof modelFunctions[modelFunctionKey]
  >[0];
};

// the actual functions of our modelFunctions, i.e. getA(), getB()
type ModelFunctions = typeof modelFunctions;

export const fetchData = async <T extends Queries>(
  queries: { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Queries ? T[K] : never } // Ensure that only valid model function keys are passed in
) => {
  // pull the keys from our queries param as an array
  const keys = Object.keys(queries) as Array<
    keyof ModelFunctions
  >;

  // pull the promises from our queries param
  const promises = keys.map((key) => modelFunctions[key](queries[key]));

  // resolve all the promises (make the API calls)
  const resolved = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  // build an object for the return data with our keys as labels
  const toReturn: { [key: string]: unknown } = {};

  // iterate over the returned data and assign it to the correct key
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    toReturn[key] = resolved[index];
  });

  // return the data in the correct type
  return toReturn as {
    [QueryKey in keyof T]: Awaited<ReturnType<ModelFunctions[QueryKey]>>;
  };
};


const data = await fetchData({
    getA: { foop: "hello" },
    getC: { boop: "bar" },

});
/** Working example. Should return the following type (only return getA and getC, not getB)
const data: {
    getA: {
        shapeOfA: {
            foop: string;
        };
    };
    getC: string;
}

.. and the following object:
const data: {
    getA: {
        shapeOfA: {
            foop: "hello";
        }
    },
    getC: "returnC";
}
*/

const data2 = await fetchData({
    getD: { msg: "hello" }, // should error because getD doesn't exist
    getC: { boop: "bar" },
});

const data3 = await fetchData({
    getA: "wrongtype", // should error because value is in the wrong format
    getC: { boop: "bar" },
});
```

A working example is at [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygQRgXhgQwgTzMGACgEcBXBAJxwC4YBvGAMxBAAdboKBLMOGAXwCU6AHxE6AKBjSYEABaZWCAPKNktMpRwShAbgmhIsRFABC6LLnxFNVWgwBGmCu1lRuvAcLRjCAIgokUgowUz9BfUNoeCQAYQtsPAIScjt6GAcWV04ePiFRIgCgkNjw-QNwaIBbEAATBAAbADFSfCguSotJaRNkABopGLMBnridcoB6CZgoOQQYAGsEHAgmEAosBoaYEEYd4Jga+u3GVuB2yr6YLgA6BBuYP16-K6ekMKukZJzeCEEJKA4JQwACydUaLTaHTAAGllqsMEscLsZkCECijhCzhdIJNpoDgSjbDgYKwKGxVqAqrlrmAoCAmNjoUR7nAHgxmGxaH45lsQC8YDchQIdmAhsh-gT5gBFVJcBAI+iDADamOaTPAcJJPFB4PVUM18IAugB+WgABWcmCqSEoEAAPINpFKMXrIedoRBVW6NbDlkbBiJlQAGI36fh4mZzLDnUiYE6+1YokAHNXunEQK63e7iwiCK4mUx5gFo3XHdOeiwuvZpxPlBAAD1Y61gUVgjC+cgAIpgoJgElYCPaACowRtQBBgWqrWWUeUQESEQa2ef2GDKmG0xbLFHDo20TfjyfT7fIvaz7gKmAmmDDjdGmC0MAIABulBFUxgAFFIMF5rNe1FBoSRfeMuFqQ49UZA0xSRVZnHmVhsAgBAIJ4CRvDEboYE-VhSC2KN5jgphySqfYNhXK8kIoa1LCwMVnBo7RpDbU9FWUBwACsEHOG44JSOcFWEbAYGQCgmMdGRTxRMFy0TQNymkXD8O2WZENIrgUNWRhSPImBKNWajrUGViyRAaktIsOCbiqRRCEIJFMMguSYK9JEjQEy83P9QQIgkQZP0CCAQAaN9NlU6MzIsq9CFspZCNE80AEkYGAeMGj+EzKlgIKQrfCCMEwAB3TAuFgc0NJQm50oAZSQKAGlQwgos0oTFJw6YHFILgGggzAxRALiePbdYEsCKBgjFWpe37IqyrkPTiJEhpMAcRoICyowZhAAAlYowDXZUkQ4dxcn3GBWgWMAQCKsV+C6CN-KU6YysoXt5hAN8NjUmBxsm1CYGmvt6L6iAIC4OAxTK7aEtAcThtPQZrOYCgv0wYA5HspEsynRsnOw51dv2o7-QsXLQtQ5UeHqBsw0GPQno6379oSoH+x1H64cCc5USUQY-pCba9omwWRIJ9cLxwLUtyRXdzuQErXtqe1hcm4c0XtWSsVc5VJa1I0RBEfRpEex7-NYtmEkV9tOx7PtCHF3o105VweUaBp+QEEYZBMWI10yLlHicCg-C9-yGYmAAqSOYAAdXWBYaUba1WEah4arkFNeuZkWxR+5g+TmzwpSIcBgJzybxRBoZYiua7jHef4LZm+wnXFVupKk+RFBUNQO87geXZOjw4GNgeBDHk3J5r4fcnDfzhX6iD85Cj2i74QbuPOagKi2tn+9GFAD877ulFUdQlXHzuh8eXkPb8aepP4Nv+G9w+-ceAWwFKefI4mc3sqAxmgAJitqVG2UAMZ20wA7NuJguxriqBAOA3I76e1fkzeQWcIKUHJBsNaaVSAoSGF2QGIAFRgAAOSwEbJpKAcC4j+yyNyYOodX46D8rvaIbMADMYDoYdkgd2GasCpJO0eEVckvApQCk-Fg-CODxKjQIZgIh8xQINHINcVYHNoySPAHwFGtl6FiMYekAOrtWFhz0EAA) which shows the errors I'm experiencing

Solution at [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygQRgXhgQwgTzMGACgEcBXBAJxwC4YBvGAMxBAAdboKBLMOGAXwCU6AHxE6AKBjSYEABaZWCAPKNktMpRwShAbgmhIsRFABC6LLnxFNVWgwBGmCu1lRuvAcLRjCAIgokUgowUz9BfUNoeCQAYQtsPAIScjt6GAcWV04ePiFRIgCgkNjw-QNwaIBbEAATBAAbADFSfCguSotJaRNkABopGLMBnridfWkJAHopmCg5BBgAawQcCCYQCiwGhpgQRj3gmBr63cZW4HbKvpguADoEO5g-Xr8bl6Qwm6RknN4IQQSKA4JQwACydUaLTaHTAAGlVusMCscPs5iCEGiTlCLldIPpgaCAIqpLgICAAHhJWgROBgCAAHlAEGBausIadoZdYbSIGIMN0YABtbHNXE81a3MAwalUWkAXVoAAVnJgqkhKJTBtJCZiDqKuXiICLIWKYeAFYMREKAAzy-T8cozOYLLCXUiYM7izpokBHA3eyA3e6PIbIQiCG4mUwRoEY8Gmw2wpHopRYxOBiDlRmsTawKKwRg-OQAEUwUEwCSsBCpqRwtPpTJZbITnMDvJEhEGtjJEFost7tZpqzEzoAopBgot5uW9mAGnSAG6eri1Y6mpiB5aIrCBGCsbAQBBrngSbxiQXO1ikHYuxYo9aMCggKqHLY98n71Wv7BYaXOChMG0aQC23NYLGUBwACsEEuO4HxSShe2EX9ZXrVYhXtCRBivG9dnmRZWGfKouCPR9iLfGAP3WA9AKqQZQKIl9SM-ZFETuKpFEIQgUXPehtRgQIoGCaUA3NSAhRReVEO4clJNWeVLD-HAIkGPRsOkZ1AggEAGkXRZPXw10mJIsiiE4lY7xgZAlQASRgYBDIBBjKlgbTdP0tcMEwAB3TAuFgJViJYu5DIAZSQKAGmPQgTJYgFyk02YHFILgGjXTBpRAaDYMLTYrKEkSYFqctKx8gK5Eoh8lIaTAHEaCAXKMOYQAAJWKMB7GFFEOHcXJFRgVoljAEAfOlfgukdDSYGdALKHLRYQH0rYCMEjrj2K0q-wyiAIC4OBpQClqrNAChAkuMDBgfO5mAoMdMGAORuJRYNWUZPjBR1NqOvknBFIwdy9OPIUeHqBksOkdScNmQqQiskqKylE7NnO2BdUGWHpSgb7hLh39Pu6pG0IVWhkD8ubagpdrcbAAAVDEKQ5HFxONJZ5REEQJgEB1ygqZqEcrbzycLYsywrQgCd6LrmDYWg-AWHYQD8AQRhkExYi6zJZeeJwKGV-gBh0VSpgAKhNmAAHVNiWXJGzVVhoqeMK5D9dK1ppqzmEV8rPF1IhwAXd2it6bahliG4RuMT5AVAgX7AEqX+JkZPZAUJRVHUJOU+zmXsj63guezqbk+LtW4l6jw4AdbC7ieTK11Wr2GlG23spgy5qD56I46z0YUHj7PpHkRQVDUAfB+T3O5YV5u-ELlP+AEg2E-L55MdKauTambDY9KgAmBJhaYUXSolleoBLLqqggOBp8aWeVZm2Z5FdtdKGfLZ6sc0gjyGEtipAOSMAAByWAjJSJQHPhrdIWtXB+F1vrAYUNd4VgAMyH38iLKAj0xaYDPsnROfgfLPl4LqN4T9U6v3pGdfKX9MA-0WMuBo5BbjrB4FZYh4A+C3U4pAghq9HBZDlgglWRtdBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By being a bit more strict with types, I have only one error left:

```js
type Queries<QueryKey extends ModelFunctionKeys> = {
  [modelFunctionKey in QueryKey]: Parameters<
    typeof modelFunctions[modelFunctionKey]
  >[0];
};

// the actual functions of our modelFunctions, i.e. getA(), getB()
type ModelFunctions = typeof modelFunctions;

export const fetchData = async <QueryKey extends ModelFunctionKeys>(
  queries: Queries<QueryKey> // Ensure that only valid model function keys are passed in
) => {
  // pull the keys from our queries param as an array
  const keys = Object.keys(queries) as QueryKey[];

  // pull the promises from our queries param
  const promises = keys.map((key) => modelFunctions[key](queries[key] as any));

  // resolve all the promises (make the API calls)
  const resolved = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  // build an object for the return data with our keys as labels
  const toReturn: { [key: string]: unknown } = {};

  // iterate over the returned data and assign it to the correct key
  keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    toReturn[key] = resolved[index];
  });

  // return the data in the correct type
  return toReturn as {
    [k in QueryKey]: Awaited<ReturnType<ModelFunctions[k]>>;
  };
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygQRgXhgQwgTzMGACgEcBXBAJxwC4YBvGAMxBAAdboKBLMOGAXwCU6AHxE6AKBjSYEABaZWCAPKNktMpRwShAbgmhIsRFABC6LLnxFNVWgwBGmCu1lRuvAcLRjCAIgokUgowUz9BfUNoeCQAYQtsPAIScjt6GAcWV04ePiFRIgCgkNjw-QNwaIBbEAATBAAbADFSfCguSotJaRNkABopGLMBnridcoB6CZgoOQQYAGsEHAgmEAosBoaYEEYd4Jga+u3GVuB2yr6YLgA6BBuYP16-K6ekMKukZJzeCEEJKA4JQwACydUaLTaHTAAGllqsMEscLsZkCECijhCzhdIJNpoDgSjbDgYKwKGxVqAqrlrmAoCAmNjoUR7nAHgxmGxaH45lsQC8YDchQIdmAhsh-gT5gBFVJcBAQAA8sq0cJJCAAHlAEGBaqswcdIedoWqIGIMN0YABtTHNJngNW0mAqqhqgC6tAACs5MFUkJQlYNpFKMeC7VDKjaw0ace7BiIrQAGN36fh4mZzLDnUiYE72yA7PYgA62mPQiBXW73cWEQRXEymWsAtGg6P5hGopShw3t8qa1jrWBRWCML5yAAimCgmASVgIytSOEdmu1uv1bYjsPhIkIg1s8ogtBdB4XquWYimMAAopBgvNZlPRQ0SQA3XNcWqHMOMzeLeFYQJSWwCAEE-HgJG8MRLUvVhSC2DN5iRVZGHJKp9g2fcFSAihfUsLAxWcHDtGkYc-xWCxlAcAArBBzhuJCUkoA9hGwZ1FzVK0UwkQYYLg7ZZnmMkQGpEDkNQ9CYEw1ZWB9KpBlIoSRKwxF4RuKpFEIQgkUgr8e03CArSRN1GO4BVDOWN1BAibjpEvQIIBABoX3mXN+MzRSuFEoh1KWBCYGQT0AEkYGAVy-nkypYHsxznM-DBMAAd0wLhYE9VDPPuVyAGUkCgBpQMIDzROsnjpgcUguAaT9MDFEBqNokd1j8wIoGCMVainGcEpSuQJKQvCGkwBxGggCKjBmEAACVijAexrSRDh3FyD0YFaBYwBABKxX4Lo0xsmBLxSygp3mEBnI2ASYBatrQJgDrp3w6qIAgLg4DFFKJr80AKECc4yMGJCbmYCgr0wYA5E0pFK11TUdMtYMppm8ycDdCxoqc0CrR4eoNS46Q9H2uyZr8+6Zx4L71l+2ApUGa6Qgm6bWvp1j4fmp0XSXCzaGQJKjtqRVGbagAVNFFQNLF9KtDn3REER9Hx1NygqcbSYSXmRzHSdp0IVnejmzlXB5RoGn5AQRhkExYjmzIuUeJwKD8M3uIJiYACpXZgAB1dYFhpTVfVYfKHiyuRiyqq7icu5g+W6zwpSIcBnwjpmxV6R6hliK4NuMd5-lI0n7CDcVC5kUvZAUJRVHUegi7LmQDcWjw4HluuBBbhWi8txvclTbjhRqz8o8ck3Y74OqaPOahleiAua9LvW59b+RFBUNQS9b0uG8eXkTb8duy-4Iv+HN0YoCtx46bAUpe9diZuPzzqACY1eSjWoHBrXMB1zukHHOaqggHAbkO9TbHwOtMeQYdPyUHJBsYaoVSAgSGOOO6IAFRgAAOSwE1J5KAP8z7WyyNye2jtj46BKg-acABmF+H1RzvwnJ1b+88kDVz8AlckvApQCkvJAuC0CfpNXgZgRB8w3wNHINcVY5NLocPAHwYG6k8EsIIekG2hsSFOz0EAA)

Comment: That is a super cool way of dealing with it, really like the <QueryKey extends ModelFunctionKeys>( queries: Queries<QueryKey>). So much to learn, I'm going to go and compare what you've changed to my original solution. Thanks!

Comment: A few small modifications and all working. I'll post the solution in the question.. feel free to update your example with this one and I'll accept the answer

Comment: Only need to change TS Config Target to ES2020 so that `Promise.allSettled` is allowed. `as any` doesn't feel so great though.

Comment: Yeah couldn't work out how to change the target on the Typescript playground, works on my local anyway. Agreed on using any but can't think of another way of doing it. You also had a typo in the toReturn line at the end